# Eliminate the black color of the "W" so that it is equal to the "S" using Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, image, image3d

I have searched the answers for a long time to help me with this but I can not find it.
I tried to do with drawing programs but it looks good.

How can I leave the "w" blank, respecting its shadows or reliefs, so that it remains the same as the "s" , without touching the "s"

attached image

[image]

Comment: perhaps a Fourier filter with the right frequency?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform hello, I would not know how to implement it, could you give an example please

Answer (score 6):

As a not too elaborated solution, it seems that a morphological image processing can be done:

```
procimg = DeleteSmallComponents[img, 140] // EdgeDetect[#, 1, 0.3] & // ColorNegate
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks, there is some way to vectorize the resulting image, so it does not come out so pixelated, or to start from an image already vectorized

Comment: @susydiaz your image is a bit small. It is normal that appears pixelated after processing. For vectorizing images you can use `ImageGraphics`. I suggest you read the doc about it.

Comment: hello, and vectorize the image with an external program (wmf), as I can import a vectorized image, I get that format can not be imported.
my idea is img = Command ..., then your code (* ImageGraphics is a command in my mathematica is not or is an external program *)

Comment: What version of MMA you have?

Comment: my version of MMA is 10.4

Comment: if you cannot use `ImageGraphics` maybe it is a command introduced in later versions...Then, you could use `Export`. Run `$ExportFormats` in MMA to see what formats you can use to export your image, and look for any appropriate vector format...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72182/discussion-between-susy-diaz-and-jose-antonio-diaz-navas).