# Remove a specific color (black) within an image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, image

I need the image to be totally blank, so the black must disappear

[image]

Comment: `ConstantImage[1, ImageDimensions[image]]`?

Comment: You should really rephrase the title (please avoid uppercase) and explain better what you need. My best interpretation is below.

Comment: I bet there is a question with the same image about something at least closely related. Hard to find though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminate the black color of the “W” so that it is equal to the “S” using Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164187/34893).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the white lines in the S with a vertical opening

```
Opening[i, {{1}, {1}, {1}}]
```

[image]

Remove the small black lines with a closing

```
Closing[%, 4]
```

[image]

Create a mask by inverting the colors and shrinking inside the boundary of the S with a 1 pixel erosion

```
mask = Erosion[1 - %, 1]
```

[image]

Add the mask to the original image

```
i + mask
(* i + Erosion[1 - Closing[Opening[i, {{1}, {1}, {1}}], 4], 1] *)
```

[image]

Comment: Well done, very clever!

Comment: +1, That is what I though OP meant, but when I read the tittle again, op said clearly to  `BLANK ALL THE IMAGE` :)  I have feeling one needs to be extra psychic these days to answer questions at stackexchange.

Comment: Sorry Nasser, my english is bad, I use translator

Comment: @Batracos , hello, it's just what I need, but it throws me an error, (mathematical use 10.4) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7laz7ni8zw6kcl5/error.png?dl=0

Comment: @juanmuñoz: MMA 10 didn't support arithmetic operators on images yet. You can convert the images to matrices, perform arithmetic on those, then convert back to image. So e.g. instead of `img1 + img2` use `Image[ImageData[img1]+ImageData[img2]]` - or upgrade to MMA 11

Comment: @NikiEstner even better, use `ImageAdd`.

Comment: @NikiEstner and @ Batracos  Hi, I've tried your combinations, but I still do not get anything, I'm doing something wrong
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vnm7nw47ljk8d7/error2.png?dl=0

Comment: @juanmuñoz: If you don't see the error, split the arithmetic expression into simplest parts and evaluate them one by one.

Comment: This is working in version 7 `ImageAdd[i, 
 Erosion[ColorNegate[Closing[Opening[i, {{1}, {1}, {1}}], 4]], 1]]`

Comment: @Batracos thank you very much virtual friend, it worked wonders